# Can't Import Data

Tags: postgresql, copy

I am trying to import some data on a table representing video club rentals (it's for a school project).

The table is represented as this:
rental(RENTAL_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,DATE_OF_RENTAL,DATE_OF_RETURN,FILM_ID),
with rental_id being the pk and customer_id and film_id being the fk of other tables (I already imported the data in them).

However, when I try to import the data on the rental table I get this error:

```
ERROR: insert or update on table "rental" violates foreign key constraint "rental_customer_id_fkey"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (customer_id)=(524) is not present in table "customer".''
```

I checked the customer table and it does not have a value of 524 for the customer ID.

What should I do? Note, that I declared all `rental_id`, `customer_id`, and `film_id` as serial. Could this be the problem? What should I do?

Comment: A `FK` is a child-parent relationship, so the child table `rental.customer_id` field needs to gave a value that matches the corresponding `id` value in the parent table `customer`. The exception being the value can be `NULL` then you don't really have a relationship. The solution is to create the `customer` and `film` tables using id values that exist in `rental`. Are you sure the data for those tables did not already include those values?  You can still use `serial` but you will need to reset the sequence after the import.

Comment: Ye I found what was wrong,the csv file didnt have the first column completely sorted(representing the id_customer) ,causing some of the rows to not get imported. What troubles me now is that after a csv sorting, importing data misses the first row. I can insert it manually, but I don't know why it doesn't import it in the first place.

Comment: What is the code you are using to do the importing? Include it in your question above. My suspicion is you are using some form of  `COPY WITH HEADER`  on a `CSV` file with no header and it is skipping the first data row as a result.

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. Indeed, I used CSV HEADER ,causing the script to miss the first row. 
Thanks for your help!